# Disabling PUT:/ and DELETE serverwide

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6.4

How would I go about disabling Put:/ and DELETE methods server wide CENTOS 6.4 x86_64 ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: -1 for lack of research. This being a site for professionals, we generally expect question askers to show that they've done at least a teeny *bit* of research into things on their own.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
<Limit PUT DELETE>
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
</Limit>
```

BTW, all of this is in the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limit).